# Appium Inpector showing XCUIElementTypeAny instead of XCUIElementTypeCell

Tags: appium, appium-ios, xcuitest, xcuielement, xcuiautomation

In a table view, there is a list of Cells we have applied accessibility IDs for that list but when I inspect it through Appium inspector it is showing `XCUIElementTypeAny` instead of `XCUIElementTypeCell` and inside the Cell, all child element is also showing `XCUIElementTypeAny` and due to this I am not able to automate those.

How to fix this issue